# Use one field to compare to another field and filter in oData

Tags: filter, odata

Lets say I have data like this (lots of it)

```
{
 "name" : "Coffee",
 "quantity": 100,
 "restock": 10
}
```

I want to use an odata `$filter` to show me ONLY items where the quantity is LESS than the restock number

Is it possible to do something like `$filter=quantity lt restock`
I know that specific example fails. Is there a way to do this? Or do I need to fetch everything and post process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query should absolutely be possible in most (all?) versions of OData: see [http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=Rating lt Price](http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products?$filter=Rating%20lt%20Price) for a working example.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work now - I must have done some noob thing to screw it up - thanks :)